# PHP jQuery trigger button on dom change

Tags: php, jquery, dom, event-handling

I have this scenario:
I have a simple php file with only few html elemnts: a div called **switch**, another called **lamp** and a couple of buttons.
The two buttons are labeled **On** and **Off**.
The lamp div is empty.
The switch div is empty too, but is updated using jQuery and Ajax with the content of a txt file, that only contains one word: it could be On or Off.
What i'm traying to achieve is this: whenever the file is updated with the word On or Off i would like the On or Off button to be triggered correspondingly and the lamp div to change the background color. Is it possible?
**UPDATE:**

Example:

```
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url : "testfile.txt",
    dataType: "text",
    success : function (data) {
       $("#switch").html(data);

       // this doesn't seems to work...
       var word = data.toLowerCase();
       $('#' + word).trigger('click');

        // this works 
        $(document).ajaxStop(function(e){
            var response = $("#switch").html();
            $("#" + response.toLowerCase()).trigger("click");
        });

        var $container = $("#switch");
        var refreshId = setInterval(function()
        {
            $container.load('testfile.txt').html();
        }, 2000);
      }
  });
}); 
})(jQuery);

<div id="switch"></div>
<div id="on" class="button">On</div>
<div id="off" class="button">Off</div>

<div id="lamp"></div>
```

Comment: When you say trigger, do you mean click, or a certain set of code is triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only one ajax request, you can do like this:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function(e){
  var response = $("#switch").text();
  // do what you want with variable response here
  $("#" + response.toLowerCase()).trigger("click");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the response is only one word. Why not try

```
var word = data.toLowerCase();
$('#' + word).trigger('click');
```

in the success callback.

Comment: Thanks, this only works if i refresh the page (after changed the content of the file), it doesn't update dinamically

Comment: @uomopalese, did you put this code in the ajax success callback? What do you mean dynamically? When the page first loads?

Comment: @AmmaCSE I updated the code to show you were I put it. I don't know why one works and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help for what you need:

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $container = $("#switch");
        $container.load("testfile.txt", function() {
            setInterval(function() {
                $container.load("testfile.txt");
            }, 2000);
        });
    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

Use `clearInterval()` to stop the timer when needed.

Comment: Where I have to put `clearIntervall()` ? The browser is sending cuntinuous requests to the server. Thanks

Comment: Your setInterval makes a request every 2s and updates the container as long as the page is loaded. This is how you can detect changes in the file. You can use clearInterval on some user action or when a certain condition is met.